# What's the Proper Way of Publishing an NPM Package with Kendo UI as Its Dependency?

Tags: angular, angular8, kendo-ui-angular2

I created an Angular library to publish as an NPM package and I've made it work. However, when I tried using Kendo UI Button for my component inside the library, I can publish to NPM but it's not very usable. After installing the NPM package in another Angular app, it won't work and I had to manually install Kendo UI Button using this command:

> ng add @progress/kendo-angular-buttons

Afterward, I tried also using that command inside my library project, it added a `node_modules` folder inside my library folder. Aside from that, it also updated the `package.json` for my library. After publishing once again and reinstalling in my other app, it now works!

However, there are a redundant `node_modules` inside my library folder and I don't want this. Can I skip using `ng add` inside my library folder and just copy the dependencies added when that command is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the Kendo UI styles in my `styles` array.

1. Generate library
2. `ng add @progress/kendo-angular-buttons`
3. Add Kendo UI Button imports to library module
4. Edit library `package.json` and `ng-package.json` to add Kendo UI dependencies

   - `dependencies` and `whitelistedNonPeerDependencies`
5. `ng build library`
6. Go inside `dist/lib`, Publish to NPM

   - use `npm init`, `npm login`, `npm publish`
7. `npm install library` in another Angular app
8. Add Kendo CSS to `styles` array in `angular.json`

```
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
  },
  "src/styles.css"
]
```